# Why is my parallel code runing very poorly?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I've been trying to parallelize my Haskell code and it has just been getting slower, so i made some sample code to show my problem
here is the serial code:

```hs
module Main where

import System.Environment

sumRangeSquares :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a -> a
sumRangeSquares start end = sum $ map (^2) [start .. end]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [start, end] <- map read <$> getArgs
    print $ sumRangeSquares start end
```

Compiled with `stack ghc -- -O2 -rtsopts -eventlog -threaded src/Main.hs` and ran with  `time ./src/Main 1 10000000`, it completes in about 0.4 seconds

Now the obvious parallel counterpart is:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import System.Environment

sumRangeSquares :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a -> a
sumRangeSquares start end = sum $ parMap rseq (^2) [start .. end]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [start, end] <- map read <$> getArgs
    print $ sumRangeSquares start end
```

Compiled the same way and ran with `time ./src/Main 1 10000000 +RTS -N4 -lf -s` takes over 6 seconds

Here's the log created by `-s`:

```
   2,661,959,552 bytes allocated in the heap
   1,891,228,032 bytes copied during GC
     468,753,512 bytes maximum residency (12 sample(s))
     307,102,616 bytes maximum slop
            1226 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1837 colls,  1837 par   10.483s   2.705s     0.0015s    0.0080s
  Gen  1        12 colls,    11 par    5.157s   1.391s     0.1159s    0.5573s

  Parallel GC work balance: 26.09% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 10 (1 bound, 9 peak workers (9 total), using -N4)

  SPARKS: 10000000 (9998153 converted, 1847 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.038s  (  0.038s elapsed)
  MUT     time    6.995s  (  2.158s elapsed)
  GC      time   15.639s  (  4.096s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.005s elapsed)
  Total   time   22.673s  (  6.297s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    380,577,209 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  30.8% of total user, 34.3% of total elapsed


real    0m6.374s
user    0m16.889s
sys 0m5.859s
```

And here is the event log as seen in `threadscope Main.eventlog`.
[image: event log of parallel code. all four HEC run and go idle at relatively the same times, with long idle times and unbalanced spark pools and spark creations]

As shown in the image, there is a lot of idle time and all four HECs run and idle at relatively the same times. Furthermore, there's lots of long idle times, and unbalanced spark pools and spark creations.

Comment: The original `sum $ map (^2) [start .. end]` likely is optimized to run in constant space -- like a tight loop. Using `parMap` here seems like a bad idea, since that will cause the list to be actually stored. Here I'd guess you want N tight loops to run in parallel, but your code isn't doing that.

Comment: @chi How would I make it run in N tight loops? I rewrote `sumRangeSquares` as `sumRangeSquares start end = sum $ withStrategy (parListChunk 4 rseq) $ map (^ 2) [start .. end]` (with `4` being the number of cores I have) and it improved the running time to about 4 seconds. But that's still nowhere near the 0.4 seconds of the serial implementation.

Comment: You must compute the sum (for a chunk) in the parallelized code instead of creating the list and then compute the sum sequentially at the end. The answer below does that: the `parMap` only creates a list of length 4, summing 4 chunks in parallel (in a tight loop), and the final sum handles those 4 final addends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cost of creating a new CPU thread is high and you are requesting to create a new thread for every tiny computation. The product of two integer costs much less then creating a new thread. So your machine is busy creating and killing new threads instead of doing useful work.

When you have a CPU, you have to give it a small amount of expensive jobs to get a performance boost.

This is, maybe awkward, but sufficient example: we leave `sumRangeSquare` the same as in sequential variant and split our range into 4 pieces, then run 4 parallel threads with `sumRangeSquares`, then sum 4 outputs in final result.

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import System.Environment

sumRangeSquares :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
sumRangeSquares (start, end) = sum $ map (^2) [start .. end]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [start, end] <- map (read :: (String -> Integer)) <$> getArgs
    let space = [(start+(i-1)*(div (end-start) 4), start+i*(div (end-start) 4)) | i <- [1..3]]
    print $ sum $ parMap rseq sumRangeSquares (space ++ [(snd $ last space, end)])
```

I used 1 and 30 000 000 as args to get more significant result and I have this for you sequential variant:

```
time ./app/Main 1 30000000

real    0m1,353s
user    0m1,350s
sys     0m0,004s
```

This for my parallel, run with one thread:

```
time ./app/Main 1 30000000 +RTS -N1 -lf

real    0m1,334s
user    0m1,311s
sys     0m0,022s
```

This for my parallel, run with four threads:

```
time ./app/Main 1 30000000 +RTS -N4 -lf

real    0m0,416s
user    0m1,386s
sys     0m0,024s
```